# What are DI, EI, and UP instructions(?) in original MS-DOS source code?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, dos, x86-16

I am going through a assembly language project for OS. For this i am getting knowledge through initial OSs. In the process i try to understand MS-DOS 1.25. But when I run this file IO.ASM then i got four errors from code of some lines as given below, here i marked the lines with "<-----this" sign. Please guide me.

```
INIT:
XOR BP,BP       ; Set up 
;stack just below I/O 
;system.
MOV SS,BP
MOV SP,BIOSSEG*16

IF  INTINP-1
MOV AL,0FFH     ; Mask all 
;interrupts.
OUTB BASE+3 <------this
ENDIF

IF  INTINP
DI  ; Set up <------ this
;keyboard interrupt vector.
MOV [BP+64H],KBINT
MOV [BP+66H],CS
EI <-----this
ENDIF

MOV [BP+4*38H],PRNFCB
MOV [BP+4*38H+2],CS
PUSH CS
POP DS
;
; Initialize time-of-day 
;clock.
;
MOV SI,STCTAB
MOV CX,4        ;Initialize 
;4 registers
UP  <------this
INITSTC:
LODB
OUT STCCOM      ;Select 
;register to initialize
LODB
OUT STCDATA
LODB
OUT STCDATA
LOOP    INITSTC

IF  SERIAL
MOV CX,4
```

I know that above given errors are obvious. But please tell me how should I modify my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error messages,did you get?

Comment: DI should be CLI. EI should be STI. OUTB needs AL as an operand (although it should be implicit). The other OUT instructions need AL also.  I can’t think of anything UP should be.

Comment: As i understood,error1: OUTB is not any instruction at all. In second error2: line DI is trying to mention destination index. In error3: EI is also an error because by EI it trying to say ES:DI. Similarly UP in error4 is also peice of any instruction which is misspelled or some of it's part is depleted.please guide me.

Comment: No, DI is not trying to use the register DI. It is the “Disable Interrupts” instruction, which in 8086 is written CLI. EI is “Enable Interrupts” and should be STI.

Comment: OUTB xx, AL is the same as OUT xx, AL. In both cases, AL needs to be written explicitly.

Comment: @prl: UP probably means `cld` because UP is 86-DOS DEBUG's symbolic name [for Direction Flag cleared](https://ulukai.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#df).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That would make a useful answer to the question, especially if we retitle it to ask what those instructions are.

Comment: If there is an answer that adequately responds to your question and may be useful you should consider accepting it as an answer. It appears you are new to SO. Upvoting and accepting an answer are tor different things. Information on what accepting an answer does and how to do it can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 10):

The MS-DOS code was originally a port of the Seattle Computer Products [86-DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86-DOS). `IO.ASM` needs to be assembled with the 86-DOS's Assembler (`ASM.COM`). The code for the assembler is in `ASM.ASM` but it needs to be assembled using itself. There are compiled versions of the 86-DOS assembler produced in the 1970s and 1980s that are still available online<sup>1</sup>. 86-DOS's assembler has roots in the Z80/8080 assemblers of the era like [Digital Research's assembler](http://www.s100computers.com/Software%20Folder/Assembler%20Collection/Digital%20Research%20ASM%20Manual.pdf) for CP/M.

86-DOS assembler uses instruction mnemonics and syntax that are a bit different than MASM in some cases:

- `EI` is Enable Interrupts. Same as `STI` in MASM
- `DI` is Disable Interrupts. Same as `CLI` in MASM
- `UP` is Direction Up (Forward) for string operations. Same as `CLD` in MASM
- `DOWN` is Direction Down (Backward) for string operations. Same as `STD` in MASM

With regards to the `IN` and `OUT` instructions where *AL/AX* as source and destination operands are the only valid choices, the 86-DOS Assembler doesn't expect them to be present.

- `OUTB imm` is equivalent to MASM's `OUT imm, al`
- `OUTW imm` is equivalent to MASM's `OUT imm, ax`
- `INB imm` is equivalent to MASM's `IN al, imm`
- `INW imm` is equivalent to MASM's `IN ax, imm`

---

### Other Information

<sup>1</sup>You can get a prebuilt `ASM.COM` from the links in this [article](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40792). There is a build disk that can be used in emulators and virtual machine like QEMU/DOSBox/BOCHS/VirtualBox with all that is needed to build the main components of MS-DOS v1.25.

Some caveats developers should be aware of is that all the files on GitHub are in Unix text format. The 86-DOS assembler chokes on Unix end of line markers. You can use `unix2dos` to convert files like `IO.ASM` to DOS format. Text files processed with the 86-DOS assembler need to end with a Control-Z end of file marker (0x1A), otherwise the assembler will never find the end of the file.

`IO.ASM`, `TRANS.ASM`, `ASM.ASM`, `HEX2BIN.ASM` are the only files in the MS-DOS 1.25 repository that require the 86-DOS assembler to process them.

- `IO.ASM` assembles to `IBMBIO.COM`/`IO.SYS` and contains the default device driver code and device initialization code.
- `ASM.ASM` is the 86-DOS Assembler
- `TRANS.ASM` is a translation tool to help migrate 8080 assembly code to 8086 assembly code
- `HEX2BIN.ASM` is a tool that converts HEX files output by the 86-DOS Assembler to DOS COM files.

The other files in the MS-DOS v1.25 repository that assemble with MASM are:

- `STDDOS.ASM` that simply sets target information then includes (`MSDOS.ASM`) which is used to produce `IBMDOS.COM`/`MSDOS.SYS` . This is effectively the DOS Kernel
- `COMMAND.ASM` is assembled to produce `COMMAND.COM` the command processor (effectively the DOS command prompt and program loader)

As noted by the the other answer, by itself these files can't simply be put on a disk. You need to create a bootloader to go in the first sector of the floppy disk image. The bootloaders are different for the different OEMs like IBM/Zenith/Compaq/SCP etc. Generally though the bootloader will read `IBMBIO.COM`/`IO.SYS` (or whatever name is used by the OEM) and `IBMDOS.COM`/`MSDOS.SYS` (or whatever name is used by the OEM). The bootloader will then usually jump to the instructions in `IBMBIO.COM`/`IO.SYS` to install and initialize the default DOS device drivers. The initialization code in `IBMDOS.COM`/`MSDOS.SYS` is then called to set up the DOS Kernel and the DOS interrupts. As the final step `COMMAND.COM` is loaded into memory and launched to provide the DOS command prompt.

The `IO.ASM` file that is included in the source code is for the 8086/8088 based SCP S-100 bus systems that were not IBM-PC compatible. Each OEM has to produce their own `IO.ASM` that is tailored to the operating environment and hardware their version of DOS will run on.

This process may differ from OEM to OEM. Some take short cuts, some don't. As DOS evolved so did the process of loading the DOS kernel and ultimately the command processor. If you were to disassemble the bootloaders for DOS you'd find OEMs doing things differently and they'd  change it as newer versions of DOS were released.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](https://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40792) states that Microsoft released only the source code of MSDOS, not the linking information nor the boot sector; also the code is not intended for current PCs. So it makes no sense trying to build this code. It is just for reading/analyzing the the source code.

Comment: Thanks to all, most of my problems are solved now, except last one, what is "UP" instruction. In which version it is used.

Comment: In order to emulate in a virtual machine, you have to have a boot sector but we have not legally. But the website above shared a msdos3.3 floppy image which include the msdos 1.25 source code and the appropriate assembler. You can assemble and run them.

Comment: I could not found a text editor inside the img but you can edit the source file by mounting the img to a specified folder( such as /tmp) if you are using a unix-like operating system